When I try to install mandos server I get a dpkg error
I've got two Raspberry Pis, both runnign diet-pi, and I install mandos server on one of them the other day but trying to install it on the second one and I just keep getting this:
Setting up mandos (1.8.16-1) ...
Job for mandos.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mandos.service" and "journalctl -xeu mandos.service" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mandos, action "restart" failed.
● mandos.service - Server of encrypted passwords to Mandos clients
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mandos.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2024-11-09 03:23:31 GMT; 48ms ago
       Docs: man:intro(8mandos)
             man:mandos(8)
    Process: 32565 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mandos --foreground $DAEMON_ARGS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 32565 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 973ms
dpkg: error processing package mandos (--configure):
 installed mandos package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mandos
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I've tried
sudo apt-get autoremove sudo apt-get --purge remove && sudo apt-get autoclean sudo apt-get -f install sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a sudo dpkg --configure -a
and
rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/mandos*
and
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/dpkg* /tmp sudo apt install -f  sudo dpkg --configure -a
but none of that has helped.

See "systemctl status mandos.service" and "journalctl -xeu mandos.service" for details.  So, what did they say?

Nothing that really helped unfortunately. I noticed from the output produced when I ran  mandos-ctl that it was complaining about something not being right in mandos.conf, so that's what helped me fix that, and after it still didn't work I just guessed that deleting mandos.service and recreating it with 'systemctl enable mandos.service' would solve it.

I've fixed this now.
There was an erroneous extra line at the start of /etc/mandos/mandos.conf which was preventing it running, but even after correcting that I still had the same error.
I deleted /lib/systemd/system/mandos.service and did 'systemctl enable mandos.service' to recreate it, and that fixed it.
